# Determine if page was refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would it be possible to determine if a webpage was accessed from the result of a refresh (pressing F5 or simply clicking the refresh button) using JavaScript? I'm also using jQuery.

Comment: What is your goal for doing this? Do you mean you want to identify when a user re-visits a page, or tell when they actually press the F5 key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `onbeforeunload()` function or jQuery [unload()](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure jQuery will help you here, but you could try

```
<html>
    <body onUnLoad='alert("Please do not leave!")'>
</html>
```

Should note that this will fire whenever the user tries to leave your page (Refresh or otherwise).